# Unable to import a class in a jsp page in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am using eclipse luna and created a project on jsp but unable to call a class from "conect " package
defined in src folder of my project

**ConnectionProviderForSql.java**

```
package connect;

    import java.sql.*;  

    public class ConnectionProviderForSql {  
    public static Connection con=null;  

    public static Connection getCon(){  
        try{  
            String DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
            String CONNECTION_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc";  
            String USERNAME="username";  
            String PASSWORD="password";  

            Class.forName(DRIVER);  
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            if(con!=null){
            System.out.println("connected");}
            else{
                System.out.println("not connected");
            }
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  

        return con;  
    }  

    }
```

my jsp file

**reseller.jsp**

```
<%@page import="connect.ConnectionProviderForSql"%>

<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%
    Connection con1=null;
    Statement stmt =null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    String result="bla";

    con1 = ConnectionProviderForSql.getCon();




        %>
```

my **browser output**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [/root/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/Panel/org/apache/jsp/reseller_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. connect.ConnectionProviderForSql resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /reseller.jsp
ConnectionProviderForSql cannot be resolved
14:     PreparedStatement ps=null;
15:     String result="bla";
16:     
17:     con1 = ConnectionProviderForSql.getCon();
18:
```

I had tried related question  but it dint solve my problem
Why it cannot resolve the class i have imported the package
Please help trying this for hours.
Thanks

Comment: did you place the .class file inside classes folder/

Comment: May be you have placed .java file there. Please keep .class file ar given location'

Comment: tried but getting the same output

Comment: where is your project deployed ? in tomcat or metadata folder of eclipse ?

Comment: why downvote,please give a reason before downvote(whoever did it)?

Comment: But in eclipse where is project deployed in tomcat directory or workspace metadata  ?

Comment: i am not getting you, i just created a  dynamic project and all the jsp file are in web content folder and xml in my web-inf.So i guess its tomcat directory

Comment: When you right click on tomcat server under server tab and click on properties you find location where your project is actually deployed by eclipse.

Comment: thanks for the help,its workspace metadata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58705/discussion-between-yagnesh-and-virendra).

Comment: Out of curiosity, place a semi-colon at the end of your connect.ConnectionProviderForSql import and see if you get a different error message.  Also try one at the end of the last import.

Answer (score 1):

The class file corresponding to ConnectionProviderForSql  should be present in the WEB-INF/classes folder. Also, it should maintain the package folder structure. If you are using eclipse to compile and run a 'Java Web Project', ideally all these should happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly not recommend to use scriplets...
Did you place ojdbc.jar into your lib folder and did you add it to your class path?
**Why dont you use servlets?**

**Why dont you use JSTL?**
Here take a look on that:
[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1)